# What is the probability the two-headed coin is chosen from among the coins that came up heads?

Tags: probability

An urn contains 3 coins; 2 biased with $P(H) = p$, and the other is a two-headed coin. All the coins are tossed at once.  If a coin is selected from those that came up heads, what is the probability that it was the two-headed coin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** For each $n\in\{0,1,2,3\}$,

- calculate the probability $P_n$ that there are exactly $n$ heads.
- calculate the probability $Q_n$ that, if $n$ heads have appeared, then the two-headed coin is chosen

Then the probability that the two-headed coin is chosen overall is
$$P_0Q_0+P_1Q_1+P_2Q_2+P_3Q_3.$$
(Do you understand why?)

Comment: very helpful thank you

Answer (score 0):

HINT: The possible results are three heads, with probability $p^2$; two heads and a tail, with probability $2p(1-p)$; and one head and two tails, with probability $(1-p)^2$. That gives half of the information embodied in the following table:

$$\begin{array}{rccc}
&3\text{ heads}&2\text{ heads}&1\text{ head}\\
\text{Probability}:&p^2&2p(1-p)&(1-p)^2\\
\text{Probability of choosing a head}:&?&?&?
\end{array}$$

You should have no trouble completing the table. How can you use these six numbers to calculate the desired probability?